# How to convert a URL containing "/../" into an absolute URL?

Tags: java, url

- INPUT:

  - Base URL: http://www.example.com/1/2/page.jsp
  - Relative URL: ../../index.jsp
- OUTPUT:

  - Absolute URL: http://www.example.com/index.jsp

How do I achieve this without using any built-in parser in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using java.net.URL. For example:

```
URL baseUrl = new URL("http:www.google.com/someFolder/");
URL absoluteUrl = new URL( baseURL , "../test.html");
```